# Get more relevant Search based on title

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using Amazon Cloud Search, Using IMDB (DEMO) data.

I am searching keywords "Crime" Its showing 85 result which have "Crime" Keywords anywhere in document.

[image]

**But I want get first those result which contains "Crime" in title and then others later.**

**Like in second screen showing 4 results. But I want all 85 records. But I want these result first and other later.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *field weighting* to boost the `title` field's effect on ranking.

If you always want results with 'Crime' in the title to appear before other results, just boost `title` to some large number, for example: 
`q.options={fields:['title^999']}`

See the docs for more:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/weighting-fields.html

Comment: Its only considering record having keywords in title field.

Comment: Its only considering record having keywords in title field. But I want find all record but only record first, where keywords contains in title field.

Comment: hmm unfortunately it sounds like specifying fields causes CS to search only those fields. You might have to specify the other fields `q.options={fields:['title^999','some_other_field',...]}`.